# How do graphics programmers deal with rendering vertices that don't change the image?

Tags: web-development, algorithms, graphics, geometry

So, the title is a little awkward.  I'll give some background, and then ask my question.

**Background**: I work as a web [GIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system) application developer, but in my spare time I've been playing with map rendering and improving data interchange formats.  I work only in 2D space.

One interesting issue I've encountered is that when you're rendering a polygon at a small scale (zoomed way out), many of the vertices are redundant.  An extreme case would be that you have a polygon with 500,000 vertices that only takes up a single pixel.  If you're sending this data to the browser, it would make sense to omit ~499,999 of those vertices.  One way we achieve that is by rendering an image on a server and and sending it as a PNG: voila, it's a point.  Sometimes, though, we want data sent to the browser where it can be rendered with SVG (or canvas, or webgl) so that it can be interactive.

**The problem**: It turns out that, using modern geographic data sets, it's very easy to overload SVG's rendering abilities.  In an effort to cope with those limitations, I'm trying to figure out ***how to visually losslessly reduce a data set for a given scale and map extent*** (and, if necessary, for a known map pixel width and height).

I got a great reduction in data size just using the [Douglas-Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm), and I believe I was able to get it to keep the polygons true to within one pixel.  Unfortunately, Douglas-Peucker doesn't preserve topology, so it changed how borders between polygons got rendered.  I couldn't readily find other algorithms to try out and adapt to the purpose, but I don't have much CS/algorithm background and might not recognize them if I saw them.

Comment: Google for "Topologically Consistent Douglas-Peucker" and you will find some links to abstracts of some articles. Unfortunately, you have to pay for the full articles I saw.

Comment: @DocBrown **Thank you!**  [Questia](http://www.questia.com/googleScholar.qst?docId=5001892504) even seems to have a free trial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `2d` `level of detail` `algorithms`.

There is much documented about this on google if you search for those highlighted terms.

[This question on stackoverflow has the information you are looking for on 2D Level of Detail rendering.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460861/2d-level-of-detail-lod-algorithm)

Comment: +1 for the very pertinent vocabulary.  It looks like I'm actually using a level-of-detail approach, but need a polygon simplification algorithm that suits my needs. [Found a neat overview for 3d ones.](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~anup/Courses/604_3DTV/Presentation_files/Polygon_Simplification/luebke01developers.pdf)  I believe I've actually worked out a suitable simplification strategy, although I haven't had time to code it.